# How to ensure in run-time that a member function in an inherited class is private? (C++, gcc)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, private-members

**A** is a base class, **B** is an inherited class. **A** takes member function pointers from **B** bound with boost::bind+boost::function to store and execute from other base class functions later. The **A** and **B** classes are in separate include files. I would like to restrict the developer who implements inherited classes from **A** that the bound member function pointers in the inherited classes are private functions. The environment is C++, gcc 4.x and Linux.

Sample:

```
------ INCLUDE FILE -----

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

struct A
{
protected:
    void Register(const char* name, boost::function<void()> FuncPtr)
    {
      // (I am not intended to pass the name argument, but probably somebody
      // knows something gcc magic which would use it to solve the problem.)
      // I want to ensure that FuncPtr points to a private member
      // function. What can be known: "B::CalledFunction" string and FuncPtr.
      // If it is not a private member function then drop an error message
      // during run-time or during compilation (???).
    }
};

------ OTHER INCLUDE FILE -----
...

struct B : public A
{
    B() : A()
    {
      Register("B::CalledFunction", boost::bind(&B::CalledFunction, this));
    }

private:
    void CalledFunction()
    {
    }
};
```

Any kind of macro magic or similar stuff can also be appreciated before/instead of a simple direct call to `A::Register()`.

Comment: _Why_ would you want to enforce this?

Comment: In C++11 the rules for access specifications were changed to be applied before SFINAE, so you would have a chance to do some macro hacks to detect whether a function is private or not. However I do not think is worth it, why must you place such artificial restriction?

Comment: what's the purpose of this? why not use inheritance the way it's supposed to be used?

Comment: The purpose: in my case, the inherited classes would implement new functions, bound and stored in the base class to call them later, but I want to prevent the developer who would use the class B to call these bound functions directly.

Comment: @kecsap, if they need to be implemented in the derived classes and the base needs to know about them anyway, why not simply use virtual functions (esp. pure virtual) and then ensure that they are private (a derived class cannot make them public).

Comment: @kecsap : Shouldn't the accessibility of the derived class' member functions be up to the derived class' author? Why should the base class care either way?

Comment: @Nim: I can't use virtual functions because the base class is generic. The derived classes implement very specific and different functions. Let's say the bound functions from the inherited class C or D do not have any common points except the function parameter signature, so they can not have common virtual functions.

Comment: @kecsap, I would argue then that they don't belong in the same inheritance hierarchy, and that you are abusing this pattern.. ;)

Comment: @kecsap, sounds like exactly what pure virtual is for...?

Comment: @Nim, I understand your point what is the purpose of the inheritance in general, I just have a different use case. Anyway as I can see from bdonlan's answer, there is no solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than expand the comments, I will propose an alternative based on really using inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A
{
  public:
    void call_a() { some_func_a(); }
  private:
    virtual void some_func_a() = 0; // pure virtual
};

class B : public A
{
  private:
    void some_func_a() { std::cout << "B::some_func_a" << std::endl; }
};

int main(void)
{
  std::auto_ptr<A> a(new B);
//  a->some_func_a();  // causes compiler error
  a->call_a();
}
```

If you leave out the definition of `some_func_a` in `B`, you'll get a compiler error when you try to instantiate `B`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the restriction you ask for is not possible. Access restrictions are only present at compile time, not runtime; the only thing they do is control (based on *lexical* scope) what identifiers can be referenced.

Since the calling context producing these bound member functions obviously has access to all its member functions, you cannot distinguish between private and public member functions locally - this rules out any macro hacks. Further, member function pointers do not retain access control information (this is why you can call a pointer to a private member function from another class). As such, checking elsewhere is also not possible.

You may be able to implement this as a compiler pass in something like [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), as the information is available there at compile time; however this is not possible with a normal C++ compiler. However, this may be prone to false positives and false negatives, as the situation in which this is an issue is somewhat ill-defined (what if some derived class  `B` *really wants* a bound public member function, that it'll use elsewhere?)